# How do I replace tags defining a node?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, textile

We're trying to move from a rather small bug tracking system to Redmine. For our old system, there's no ready migration solution script available, so we want to do that ourselves.

I suggested using Nokogiri to move some of the formatting over to the new format (Textile), however, I ran into problems.

This is from the DB field in our old system's DB:

```
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

This needs to be translated into Textile, and it would look like this:

```
* list item 1
* list item 2
```

Now, starting to parse using Nokogiri, I'm here:

```
def self.handle_ul(page)
        uls = page.css("ul")
        uls.each {|ul|
                lis = ul.css("li")
                lis.each { |li|
                        li.inner_html = "*" << li.text << "\n"
                }
        }
end
```

This works like a charm. However, I need to do two replacements:

```
<li>
</li>
```

tags need to be removed from the `<li>` object, and:

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

tags need to be removed from the `<ul>` object. However, I cannot seem to find the actual tags in the object representing it. `inner_html` returned only the HTML between the tags I'm looking for:

```
ul.inner_html
```

Results in:

```
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
```

Where can I find the tags I need to replace? I thought about using `parent` and reassociate the child `<li>` tags with the `parent.parent`, but that would order them at the end of the grandparent.

Can I somehow access the whole HTML representation of an object, without stripping its defining tags out, so that I can replace them?

---

EDIT:

As requested, here is a mockup of an old DB entry and the style it should have in textile.

Before transformation:

```
Fixed for rev. 1.7.92.

<h4>Problems:</h4>
<ul>
<li>fixed.</li>
<li>fixed. New minimum 270x270</li>
<li>fixed.</li>
<li>fixed.</li>
<li>fixed.</li>
<li>fixed. Column types list is growing horizontally now.</li>
</ul>
```

After transformation:

```
Fixed for rev. 1.7.92.

h4.Problems:
* fixed.
* fixed. New minimum 270x270
* fixed.
* fixed.
* fixed.
* fixed. Column types list is growing horizontally now.
```

---

EDIT 2:

I tried to overwrite parts of the `to_s` method of the Nokogiri elements:

```
li.to_s["<li>"]=""
```

but that doesn't seem to be a valid lvalue (not that there is an error, it just doesn't do anything).

Comment: Why you want the *tag replacement*, rather you can directly extract the text, right? Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: I need to preserve the document as a whole, only changing certain tag structures. If I would extract the text, I would need to know where it goes in the target document, information that would be lost.

Comment: so you want to restructure the existing document with the removal of the tags `li` and `ul`.  Can you show us the output in more explicit way? after the replace what would be the resultant html?

Comment: Restructure might be the wrong word. I have a document in a database field that represents HTML. I need the document intact in it's structure (where the text pieces are), but the formatting for the text pieces need to be represented by a different formatting than HTML tags.

Comment: ookay! give that exact expected output to see how does it look like.

Comment: you removed `</h4>` too. Is it intentionally?

Comment: I replaced <h4> with .h4, which is the textile equivalent for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basis for such a transform:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
EOT
puts doc.to_html

doc.search('ul').each do |ul|
  ul.search('li').each do |li|
    li.replace("* #{ li.text.strip }")
  end
  ul.replace(ul.text)
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Running that outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><ul>
<li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul></body></html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>* list item 1
    * list item 2
</body></html>
```

I didn't intend, or attempt, to make the first "item" have a leading carriage-return or line-feed. That's left as an exercise for the reader. Nor did I try to handle the `<h4>` tags or similar substitutions. From the answer code you should be able to figure out how to do it.

Also, I'm using `Nokogiri::HTML` to parse the HTML, which turns it into a full HTML document with the appropriate DOCTYPE header, `<html>` and `<body>` tags to mimic a full HTML document. That could be changed using `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse` instead but wouldn't really make a difference in the output.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE If you do this, consider releasing a gem!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [ClothRed](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ClothRed/frames/index), which is an HTML to Textile converter in Ruby. It hasn't been updated in a while, but it's simple and may be a good starting point for your own converter.

If you really want to use Nokogiri, you're writing a filter, so you may want to use the SAX interface.

Comment: I will take a look, maybe this will save us the trouble. Thanks. +1

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much of a "converter". There's no parsing going on, it straight up replaces the HTML tags with textile tags. Sadly, hardly any HTML nowadays is that easy.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to convert. If it is the output of a javascript in-browser rich text editor, then it may be consistent enough to do that. If it's arbitrary HTML, then you're better off with the parsing solution, such as the Tin Man's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try McBean (https://github.com/flavorjones/mcbean) [caveat: I'm the author of the gem, and it hasn't been updated in a while].

It's similar to ClothRed in spirit, but uses Nokogiri under the hood and actually transforms the document structure into output text. It supports substantial subset of Textile; and in fact I've used it successfully to convert wiki pages between wiki systems, as you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody interested finds this later, another alternative is to use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). I've just did my first tests, and it seems almost sufficient, and it can do many more formats.